# Python 2.7 Backport: enum classes are not instances of abstact enum classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working in the pypi enum34 backport of the Enum class for Python 2.7.

Consider the following:

```
from enum import *

class ArtTools(Enum):
    pass

class Paintbrushes(ArtTools):
    four_inch_brush = 1
    two_inch_brush = 2
    fan_brush = 3
    paint_knife = 4

print type(Paintbrushes.fan_brush) # <enum 'Paintbrushes'>
assert isinstance(Paintbrushes.fan_brush, ArtTools)  # True/No Error

print type(Paintbrushes) # <class 'enum.EnumMeta'>
assert isinstance(Paintbrushes, ArtTools) # AssertionError
```

Is there a reason Paintbrushes are not ArtTools? This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Paintbrushes` is class, not an instance, therefore it won't be an instance of `ArtTools` or any other class.

Comment: It is my understanding that enum classes should not have instances. Is there another way to assert if an object (i.e. passed reference) is an ArtTools?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that `issubclass(Paintbrushes, ArtTools)` would return true. Could that potentially be a fix for you?